# SQL Does it make sense to re-order database instead of using ORDER BY to increase performance?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with around 120.000 Entries and I need to do substring comparisons (where ... like 'test%') for an autocomplete function. The database won't change.

I have a column called "relevance" and for my searches I want them to be ordered by relevance DESC. I noticed, that as soon as I add the "ORDER BY relevance DESC" to my queries, the execution time increases by about 100% - since my queries already take around 100ms on average, this causes significant lag.

Does it make sense to re-order the whole database by relevance once so I can remove the ORDER BY? Can I be certain, that when searching through the table with SQL it will always go through the database in the order that I added the rows?

This is how my query looks like right now:

```
select *
from hao2_dict
where definitions like 'ba%'
   or searchable_pinyin like 'ba%'
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

UPDATE: For context, here is my DB structure:
[image]

And some time measurements:
Using an Index (relevance DESC) for the search term 'b%' gives me 50ms, which is faster than not using an Index. But the search term 'banana%' takes over 1700ms which is way slower than not using an Index. These are the results from 'explain':

b%:

0   Init    0   27  0       0
1   Noop    1   11  0       0
2   Integer 100 1   0       0
3   OpenRead    0   5   0   9   0
4   OpenRead    2   4223    0   k(2,-,) 0
5   Rewind  2   26  2   0   0
6   DeferredSeek    2   0   0       0
7   Column  0   6   4       0
8   Function    1   3   2   like(2) 0
9   If  2   13  0       0
10  Column  0   4   6       0
11  Function    1   5   2   like(2) 0
12  IfNot   2   25  1       0
13  IdxRowid    2   7   0       0
14  Column  0   1   8       0
15  Column  0   2   9       0
16  Column  0   3   10      0
17  Column  0   4   11      0
18  Column  0   5   12      0
19  Column  0   6   13      0
20  Column  0   7   14      0
21  Column  2   0   15      0
22  RealAffinity    15  0   0       0
23  ResultRow   7   9   0       0
24  DecrJumpZero    1   26  0       0
25  Next    2   6   0       1
26  Halt    0   0   0       0
27  Transaction 0   0   10  0   1
28  String8 0   3   0   b%  0
29  String8 0   5   0   b%  0
30  Goto    0   1   0       0

banana%:

0   Init    0   27  0       0
1   Noop    1   11  0       0
2   Integer 100 1   0       0
3   OpenRead    0   5   0   9   0
4   OpenRead    2   4223    0   k(2,-,) 0
5   Rewind  2   26  2   0   0
6   DeferredSeek    2   0   0       0
7   Column  0   6   4       0
8   Function    1   3   2   like(2) 0
9   If  2   13  0       0
10  Column  0   4   6       0
11  Function    1   5   2   like(2) 0
12  IfNot   2   25  1       0
13  IdxRowid    2   7   0       0
14  Column  0   1   8       0
15  Column  0   2   9       0
16  Column  0   3   10      0
17  Column  0   4   11      0
18  Column  0   5   12      0
19  Column  0   6   13      0
20  Column  0   7   14      0
21  Column  2   0   15      0
22  RealAffinity    15  0   0       0
23  ResultRow   7   9   0       0
24  DecrJumpZero    1   26  0       0
25  Next    2   6   0       1
26  Halt    0   0   0       0
27  Transaction 0   0   10  0   1
28  String8 0   3   0   banana% 0
29  String8 0   5   0   banana% 0
30  Goto    0   1   0       0

Comment: Don't you have an index on `relevance` and of course on `definitions`? If you remove the `order by`you don't have a garanteed order in your output.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I be certain, that when searching through the table with SQL it will always go through the database in the order that I added the rows?

No. SQL results have no inherent order. They *might* come out in the order you inserted them, but there is no guarantee.

Instead, put an index on the column. Indexes keep their values in order.

However, this will only deal with the sorting. In the query above it still has to search the whole table for rows with matching definitions and searchable_pinyins. In general, SQL will only use one index per table at a time; usually trying to use two is inefficient. So you need one multi-column index to make this query not have to search the whole table *and* get the results in sorted order. Make sure `relevance` is first, you need to have the index columns in the same order as your order by.

`(relevance, definitions, searchable_pinyins)` will make that query use only the index for searching and sorting. Adding `(relevance, searchable_pinyins)` as well will handle searching by definitions, searchable_pinyins, or both.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! To be honest I never used indexes for anything other than my primary keys before. I experimented quite a bit with setting different indexes today and measuring the execution time, but there is one thing I noticed: Using indexes (e.g. the compsite one you proposed) seem so significantly improve the performance for searches with very little characters - but the more characters I add to the search string the slower it gets. For me, the searches will actually get slower than the ones without any index after exceeding around 6-10 characters. Is this normal?

Comment: @Basti That seems a bit odd. Try [analyzing your tables](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) to make sure the query planner's statistics are up to date. Use [`explain query plan <your query>`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) and see if there's any difference in the plans. Note that `foo%` will use the index but `%foo` will not.

Comment: Not sure how to check that, this is the result that I get from explain query plan ...:
SCAN TABLE hao2_dict USING INDEX hao2_index
And yes, I'm only using one % wildcard at the end of the string.

Comment: @Basti That indicates it is using an index called hao2_index.

Comment: That's the composite index. I edited the post to add a picture of my current DB setup. If there is nothing wrong, I think I will just revert leaving out the "order by" and the "limit" and then doing the ordering in my code, that should give me a somewhat acceptable performance.

Comment: @Basti Try it, but I'd be very surprised if it is faster. SQLite should not even have to sort, it can read from the sorted index, and then feed you only the first 100 rows. You will have to slurp all results into memory, sort, and then discard all but the first 100.

Comment: @Basti You can try using `explain <query>` to get more detailed analysis. Try it with your different lengths of searches and see if it changes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using only one Index on the relevance now. Not sure what I can learn from the result of 'explain' but I updated my original post. I just don't understand how it can make the performance worse when I add the "relevance DESC" index. 'explain query plan' shows me that the index is being used: SCAN TABLE hao2_dict USING INDEX relevance_index

Comment: @Basti Sorry the explain wasn't any help, they look exactly the same. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot for the help! I will experiment a bit more and update this post if I find a solution.